# cannot cancel country boundary in plotly scatter_mapbox

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

New to plotly, I'm trying drawing a scatter_map. For some reason, I want to cancel the country border by the code as follows:

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
        df, lat="lat", lon="lon", color="var_c", size='var_s',
        custom_data=['city', 'var_c', 'var_s'],
        mapbox_style="open-street-map",
        center=dict(lat=34.3227, lon=108.5525), 
        zoom=3
    )
fig.update_geos(
        showcountries=False
    )
```

But only the  `px.scatter_mapbox` works and coutry boundaries have not be deleted.
While I use `go.Scattergeo()`, It works:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig.update_geos(
        showcountries=False
    )
```

I want to know whether update_geos conflict with px.scatter_mapbox(according to offical tutorial, they don't conflict), and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The map box is a map with switchable tiles, and the Geo map has map information in outline format so you can hide borders. See here for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

I solved this question, actually `px.scatter_mapbox` can't be changed by  `update_geos`. And if anyone else want to change the style of scatter_mapbox, there is my solution:

```
fig.update_layout(
        mapbox=dict(
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            style='mapbox://styles/your_customed_style'
        )
    )
```

`mapbox_access_token` is a string defined before. It's your own mapbox token, you can get it through https://docs.mapbox.com/ .

And you can create a new style of mapbox (https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-custom-style/ may helps), to delete country boundary, to change themes of map, or do anything you want to do.